# Maldet having problems with systemctl

Tags: pam, systemctl

Trying to start maldet daemon. Following shows up: 
"Job for maldet.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration."
I have configured the 'maldetect/monitor_paths' file to include root and user folder but the error still shows up. 
Then I get the following for "systemctl status maldet.service":

```
service - Linux Malware Detect monitoring - maldet
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/maldet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Mon 2019-08-12 04:10:43 CEST; 3min 7s ago
  Process: 15202 ExecStart=/usr/local/maldetect/maldet --monitor USERS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)<br/>
```

And for "journalctl -xe"

```
Aug 12 03:40:02 server polkit-agent-helper-1[14115]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): conversation failed
Aug 12 03:40:02 server polkit-agent-helper-1[14115]: pam_unix(polkit-1:auth): auth could not identify password for [user]
```

How to fix that?